# Why is the eigenvector of the smallest eigenvalue of this matrix gives the intersection of a set of lines in homogenous coordinates?

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, analytic-geometry, projective-geometry

Consider $L = \{l_1 \cdots l_n\}$ be a set of lines in the plane in homogeneous coordinates. In this definition, a line $ax+by+c = 0$ is given by its direction $l^T = (a/c,b/c,1)^T$ such that it consists of the points where $l^T(x,y,1)^T=0$. Now suppose that I want to find the intersection of lines in $L$, assuming that it exists. Otherwise, I want to find the point given by the least square solution had I written all this as a system of linear equations.

I have found a PDF that claims the eigenvector of the smallest eigenvalue of this matrix is the answer:

$$M = \sum_i l_i l_i^T$$

I wonder why this is true. In case anyone wonders where I have found this, here's the link: [click here](http://alumni.media.mit.edu/~maov/classes/comp_photo_vision08f/lect/21_SingleView.pdf).

Comment: I don’t see where those slides claim that this gives you the least-squares solution to the intersection problem. Also, there are better estimates of vanishing points than the point that minimizes the sum of the squared distances to the lines. See the end of section 8.6 in [Hartley & Zisserman](https://www.amazon.com/Multiple-View-Geometry-Computer-Vision/dp/0521540518) for a brief discussion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $v=(x,y,1)^T$ is the intersection of all lines, then $l_i^Tv=0$ for every $i$, i.e. $l_il_i^Tv=\vec 0$ for every $i$. It follows that $Mv=\vec 0$, i.e. $v$ is an eigenvector of $M$ with zero eigenvalue.

If the known coefficient of the lines are only approximations of their real values, then the eigenvalue is not zero, but very near to it (of course we are supposing the approximations to be very good). Hence the claim is true, provided we specify "the smallest eigenvalue in modulus".

Very likely, this is also the point given by the least square solution, in case the lines don't coverge: it shouldn't be difficult to carry out the computation and verify the claim.

EDIT.

I must retract my last sentence above: in general, the eigenvector with smallest eigenvalue does not yield the least square solution.

Here's a counterexample: lets take three non-coverging lines $l_1=(1,-1,1)$, $l_2=(-1,-1,1)$, $l_3=(0,-2,1)$. If $v=(x,y,1)^T$ and $l_iv=a_i$, then to find the least square $v$ we have to minimize $S=\sum_i a_i^2$. But:
$$
{\partial S\over\partial x}=2\sum_i a_i{\partial a_i\over\partial x}=
2\sum_i v^Tl_i^Tl_i{\partial v\over\partial x}=2v^TM\pmatrix{1\\0\\0}
\quad\text{and}\quad
{\partial S\over\partial y}=2v^TM\pmatrix{0\\1\\0}.
$$
You can verify that imposing $\partial S/\partial x=0$ and 
$\partial S/\partial y=0$ gives as solution $v=(0,2/3,1)$.

On the other hand, the smallest eigenvalue of $M$ is $(9-\sqrt{73})/2$, corresponding to the eigenvector 
$v=(0,(\sqrt{73}-3)/8,1)$, which is different from the solution found above.

Comment: Thanks for the answer (+1), but my problem is actually the last paragraph of your answer. No offense, but I already knew the other paragraphs.

Comment: The slides you linked never mention the least square solution: is that a conjecture or do you have some other source?

Comment: Yes, you're correct. It never mentions it. No, I don't have another source unfortunately. So, yes. It's a conjecture, but it's the most reasonable interpretation of what it claims. In case it means something else, I still would like to see a proof.

Comment: See my edited answer: the conjecture is false.

Comment: Beautiful counter-example. I wish I could upvote you twice. Anyway, I still feel kind of uncomfortable with the method above. I don't know what kind of solution it gives when the lines don't have an intersection. I have no intuition about it. Do you have any intuition about what it does? Besides just being a mere approximation.

Comment: Because of continuity, the smallest eigenvalue solution is near to the least square solution if all lines are almost-converging. But in a general case I really don't know if that is still true.

Comment: It's very probable that it's not true: consider three non-concurrent lines. Then they form a triangle. The least square solution is the center of mass of this triangle if I'm not mistaken. As the triangle gets larger and larger, it seems very likely that the solution given by the smallest eigenvalue gets farther apart from the least square solution. Am I right?

Comment: If you expand my counterexample by considering $l_3=(0,-1/a,1)$, where $a$ is a real number, you can see for instance that for $-1/2<a<0$ the smallest eigenvalue solution is $(1,0,0)$, which isn't even a point.